# Use crontab to restart an Upstart service on schedule?

Tags: 12.04, cron, upstart

I need to restart `shiny-server` (Upstart service) on Ubuntu 12.04 on a routine schedule.

Typically, if I want to restart this service manually, I simply type: `sudo restart shiny-server` or `service shiny-server restart` (as `root`). As I understand, this is similar to something like `sudo restart mysql`.

To schedule the restart, I tried the following entries in my `root` user's `crontab`:

```
 0 6 * * * restart shiny-server
 0 6 * * * service shiny-server restart
 0 6 * * * bash /home/local/ANT/raybao/dev/script.sh
```

Where the last line of `script.sh` is `service shiny-server restart`.

**None of the above actually works!**

So I'm pretty stumped/confused. What am I missing? Thanks!!

More info for `shiny-server` here: http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/#upstart-ubuntu-12.04-through-14.10-redhat-6

Comment: As the answer below notes, /usr/sbin/service can't be called from cron for some reason, but /sbin/restart service_name does work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're on the correct path adding this to the root user's `cron`.

#### Full system paths

When using `cron`, you want to be sure to use **full system paths** for commands and files.  You can use the `which` command to find out where `restart` is located: `which restart`.  For me, it shows `/sbin/restart`.

So, using this information, the cron would look as follows:

```
0 6 * * * /sbin/restart shiny-server
```

which would restart the server at 6:00AM system-time.

#### Output to /dev/null

When `cron` runs, it will e-mail *any* output to the user who is running the cron jobs.  If you don't want this, which you probably don't, the command you'd run would look like this:

```
0 6 * * * /sbin/restart shiny-server > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This will output both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`, instead of being read by `cron`.

#### Edit

I originally misunderstood and thought that this service was runing using `init`, when it is in fact using `upstart`.  The moral of the story remains **use full system paths** when using `cron`.

Comment: When I typed `which shiny-server`, I got `/usr/bin/shiny-server`. So thus, I added the line `30 13 * * * /usr/bin/service shiny-server restart` (testing for 1:30pm), and unfortunately, it did not restart the service as expected. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: I also added the same line to the end of my `script.sh` and tried calling that in my `crontab` as well. `script.sh` contains add'l MySQL commands (which ran successfully), but the last line to restart the service did not.

Comment: You're misunderstanding.  We don't care where `shiny-server` is.  We care where `service` is.  Please try the answer again with that in mind.  I gave you what should be a working example :D

Comment: I am correct that I read that `sudo service shiny-server restart` successfully restarts the service?  In that case, I think that the examples provided should work.

Comment: Hmm... I added the **exact** line you posted in your solution, except changed `sbin` to `bin` (because that's where `which service` returned), but it still did not work...

Comment: Okay, sounds like you've got it now, but what does `sudo which service` say?

Comment: Ahh yes, running `which service` as `root` returns `/usr/sbin/service`. However, I just added this to my crontab and it still did not restart. So weird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30447/discussion-between-earthmelon-and-ray).